# TDateTimePicker and Date

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

It's a simple question for a weird thing of DatetTimePicker from Delphi XE7.

I have this code...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DateTimePicker1.Date:= Date;
  memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(Date) + ' vs ' + FloatToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date));
end;
```

Today, 18 of March 2015, after I press the button the results I get is:

```
42081 vs 42081.846316956
```

If I press again after 5 minutes I get the same result.
Why the values are not the same?

Comment: The TDateTimerPicker only updates the date part and leaves the time unchanged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Date()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.Date) function truncates the decimal portion of the return value (sets the time portion to 0).  So it returns the current date/time with only the date filled in.

The `TDateTimePicker.Date` property setter only updates the date portion of the internal stored `TDateTime`, leaving the existing time intact.  The `TDateTimePicker.Date` property getter returns the entire internal stored date/time, not the date by itself, as one would expect.  So you are seeing the updated date + the original time as initialized by `TDateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 2):

- The `TDateTimePicker.Date` and `TDateTimePicker.Time` property getters return both a full date/time value, despite their names. The property setters, on the other hand, update only the date and time portions, respectively, as expected.
- The `Date()` function returns a `TDateTime` that just contains a date portion, no time portion.

To retrieve just the date portion by itself, you can use the `DateOf()` function from the `DateUtils` unit to strip off the time portion of the value returned by the `TDateTimePicker.Date` or `TDateTimePicker.DateTime` properties:

```
DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date)
```

Comment: [QC #6425](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=6425) ("DateTimePicker Date and Time functions actually return date-times") is closed "as designed"!  [QC #47614](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=47614) ("TDateTimePicker Date property returns a time portion even though it is not documented to do so") and [QC# 61716](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=61716) (Date property returns Date AND Time) are still open.

Answer (score 1):

Set Datepicker1.Time to 0 and you'll get the same results.
It's the fraction of the daytime passed you see in the decimals.